# Print number of matching sequence in the user given input for the constant input

Tags: c++

I wrote a code to get the number of sequences occurring in the user input sequence.

This is my code. It excludes the subsequence which I wish to be tested.

I need to consider 12,23,34,123,234,1234 as sequences.

Overlapping of sequences should not be considered (12 in 123 should not be considered).

For e.g. constant number 1234

User given number 124312341211423

Output : No.of Sequence found 4

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string num1;
string seq;
cout << "Enter constant number: ";
cin >> num1;
cout << "Enter the sequence: ";
cin >> seq;
int count=0;
for (int t=0; t<=num1.size()-2; t++)
{
string num = num1;
for (int k = num1.size(); k>=2-t ;k--)
{
cout << num <<"\n";
if (t==2 && k<=2)
break;
//num=num.substr(t,t+k-1);
for (int j = 1; seq.find(num) != string::npos; j++)
{
seq = seq.substr(0,seq.find(num)) + " " + seq.substr(seq.find(num)+num.size());
count = count + 1;
}
num = num.substr(t,t+k-1);
}
cout<< seq << "\n";
}
cout << "No. of sequences found: " << count << "\n";
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I tried running your code and I got it outputting 5 sequences found. I'm assuming your request is to figure out why it's not 4.

I'll make a couple recommendations:

1. The logic of your for-loops and forming `num` should be adjusted to test all substrings of `num1` such that each substring is at least 2 characters in length.
2. Change your most-interior for-loop into a while loop, because your iterator `j` really isn't doing anything.
3. Call `string::find()` once per iteration of your most-interior loop. `String::find()` is expensive and you call it three times without changing the arguments.
4. Pull the declaration of `num` out of the for-loop so it's only declared once.

Here is the result of these recommendations in effect:

You'll notice I added a variable `numStart` to save the location of the beginning of `num` in `seq`, thus allowing recommendation #3 to be done.

I also moved `cout << seq << "\n"` into the most-interior loop so you can see the state of `seq` every time a sequence is found.

```
int main() {
string num1;
string num;
string seq;
cout << "Enter constant number: ";
cin >> num1;
cout << "Enter the sequence: ";
cin >> seq;
int count=0;
for (int t=0; t<=num1.size(); t++) {
    for (int k = num1.size(); k>t+1; k--) {
        num = num1.substr(t, k-t);
        size_t numStart = seq.find(num);
        while (numStart != string::npos) {
            seq = seq.substr(0, numStart) + " " + seq.substr(numStart + num.size());
            count++;
            numStart = seq.find(num);
            cout << seq << "\n";
        }
    }
}
cout << "No. of sequences found: " << count << "\n";
return 0;
}
```

I hope this helps!